# Client Side VBScript Program To Access Database - Not Working Peoperly

Tags: vbscript

I have the following VBScript Client side code. It is NOT working as expected. First error is - "MethodDatabase" not recognized. Did I miss something ? I just want to display the records from table T which is in SQL Server database.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Database Sample Program </title>
        <script type="text/vbscript">
        Sub MethodDatabase()
            Dim connection
            Dim connectionstring
            Dim rs

            Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            connectionstring = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SQLTEST;Initial Catalog=Sample;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
            connection.Open connectionstring

            Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            rs.Open("SELECT * FROM T", connection) ' Table Name Is - "T" With Two Columns - "X" & "Y" 
            rs.MoveFirst

            While Not (rs.eof)
                MsgBox (rs.fields(0) & " - " & rs.fields(1))
                rs.MoveNext
            Wend

            rs.close
            connection.close
        End Sub
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="form1">
            <input type="button" name="button1" value="Click" onClick="MethodDatabase()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
rs.Open("SELECT * FROM T", connection)
```

To:

```
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM T", connection
```

In VBScript, you [don't use parens](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) when calling routines that don't return values (unless you use the `Call` statement).